# How to generate sound check data per album?

Tags: itunes, audio, sound-volume

In [Mastered for iTunes](https://www.apple.com/itunes/mastered-for-itunes/docs/mastered_for_itunes.pdf), Apple promises:

> Sound Check can also correctly set the volume per album, rather than per song, allowing albums that rely on volume differences between tracks

However, my understanding is that `afconvert` (with the `--soundcheck-generate` and `--soundcheck-read` options) only works on track-level.

How can I generate soundcheck data from multiple files and apply it to a whole album?